# How to Build and Release ASP.NET Core 2.1 apps with TFS 2013 and Release Management 2013?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, msbuild, release-management

## How to Build and Release ASP.NET Core 2.1 with TFS 2013?

We have a TFS 2013 Server which is responsible for MSBuild and Release Management Client (and agents) 2013 to release (deploy) to IIS Servers.
For ASP.NET 4+ we create Build and Release templates, now:

> Can we use TFS 2013 and Release Management 2013 to build and deploy ASP.NET Core 2.1 applications? Or do we need to migrate to TFS 2017 and use Task based Builds and release instead?

If Yes, can somebody share some links/insights?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried scripts to call `dotnet publish` or similar `dotnet` commands?